# Is Apple's Swift a case sensitive language?

Tags: swift, case-sensitive

How does Swift deal with case sensitivity? If you define var "someNum" and later reference "somenum" without defining it does it correct it to "someNum" or give you an error?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Don't have a developer account.

Comment: I think you can assume 99% of real (not parody/for fun) programming languages are case sensitive.

Comment: This is true, but seems largely just a case of that being what programmers are used to. There are few intrinsic benefits and quite a few risks.

Comment: @user3713329: I'm curious as to what these so called "risks" are.  Case insensitivity is a pain in the ass. `Dim Str as String  Dim str as String`. yuck.

Comment: Especially in languages where you do not explicitly define variables, you can very easily create a new variable by using "somenum" when you meant "someNum". It also hurts readability: if you actually have somenum and someNum on purpose this is likely to lead to confusion (same is true of sumNum, but case insensitivity does not "solve" that).

What are the real benefits of case sensitivity in programming languages? Programmers are used to it… and there are some naming conventions which suggest using different caps but same spelling for related constructs. What else?

Comment: "Why don't you try it?"  You assume that every property of a system is an intended property.  That's not usually true.   Worse, given that Swift is "just out", there is every reason to believe the implementation is rough around the edges.

Comment: `QBASIC` was a REAL programming language :D

Comment: @user3713329: Your thinking is English-centered. In a natural-language-agnostic context, case insensitivity can lead to ambiguity. Turkish uppercase “I” is a classic example: downcased, it becomes “ı” (without a dot) – not “i”, for which the uppercase counterpart is “İ” (with a dot). As another example, in French, lowercase “mangé” may become “MANGÉ” or “MANGE” when uppercased, depending on arbitrary preference. Collision will occur if lowercase “mange” is also used.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a case sensitive language. If you try to reference a variable with the wrong case, you'll get a `use of unresolved identifier` error. XCode will suggest spellings as you're typing, but doesn't offer a solution after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

OP: if you have `dict["key"] = "value"`, you can write something so that `dict.str("key") == "value"`, `dict.Str("key") == "Value"`, and `dict.STR("key") == "VALUE"`. Case senstivie is not completely useless.